# User can copy hidden field data?

Tags: html, cross-browser, hidden-field

I have a form with many hidden fields. When a user selects text from the form and pastes it in to a text editor - they can see the values of the hidden fields. This doesn't happen to everyone. However, for the users that are experiencing this, they experience it across all browsers. I haven't been able to replicate this. Any clues as to what might be the problem?

Cheers,

Comment: Can you show some code for your hidden fields?

Comment: What browser? How are they selecting? Are they selecting text within a single field, or "click here, drag to there" which covers the area where the hidden fields would be if they were visible?

Comment: they select the areas which would cover the hidden fields if they were visible. Both IE and Firefox for some users. Same versions of IE or FF couldn't reproduce the bug on my machines. Other users have no problems whatsoever. So I'm tempted to think it's an OS thing or something.

Comment: Are you saying the hiddne fields when highlighted -> copy & pasted end up showing as visible fields?  Please show example code of this, first I hear of hidden fields being copy ready & displaying.

Answer (score 0):

How did you hide the fields?  If you used CSS `visibilty:hidden` then the fields still take up space on the rendered page and may or may not be selectable.  To hide fields with CSS use `display:none` which should prevent the browser from allocating rendered space on the page.

Remember that no matter how they're hidden, "view source" will reveal them, so don't put security-sensitive data in them.